# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes when suspeding

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 16.04, suspend

I have a Lenovo z40-70 Laptop with a Geforce 820M. Whenever my Ubuntu suspends it freezes. It only shows a black screen and doesn't respond to any command. 
I had the same issue when I was using Ubuntu 14.04. I tried a lot of things to solve it (including updating my graphic card which caused my video to crash). I was expecting for this issue to get solved in Ubuntu 16.04. 
That's not the case though.

Any thoughts?